# Log4j2 Not Logging in External File

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I am using log4j2 in my java application to log the error messages and output to console as well as an external log file. It is successfully logging the messages to console but its not logging the messages to external log file. Following is the log4j2.properties files that I am using-

```
status = error
name = PropertiesConfig

property.filename = <filePath>\\finderApp.log

filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
filter.threshold.level = debug

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = [%-5p] %d %c - %m%n
appender.console.filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
appedner.console.filter.threshold.level = error

appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
appender.rolling.fileName = ${filename}
appender.rolling.filePattern = <filePath>\\finderApp-bkp-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true

loggers = rolling

logger.rolling.name = <package for main class>
logger.rolling.level = info`enter code here`
logger.rolling.additivity = false
logger.rolling.file.appenderRefs = rolling
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile

rootLogger.level = info
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

Is there something that I am missing in this properties file?

Answer (score 0):

Try below `logger` configuration -

```
logger.xxx.name = xxx
logger.xxx.level = info
logger.xxx.additivity = false
logger.xxx.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile
logger.xxx.appenderRef.console.ref = STDOUT

rootLogger.level = error
rootLogger.additivity = false
rootLogger.appenderRef.console.ref = STDOUT
rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile
```

Where xxx is root package name in which all classes and subpackages of your project are present.

Comment: This configuration is creating the log file but the file is empty, it does not contain any logs. Any other approach that you could think of?

Comment: @KetanDeopujari what about console logs ? Are they getting generated with this configuration ?.

Comment: Yes Console Logs are getting generated correctly with above configuration.

Comment: @KetanDeopujari I just updated above configuration. Sorry, I missed one point. Can you check now. If you face problem even then, change `status = trace` in the first line of your configuration. It will generate detail logs of log4j2 for debugging purpose.

Comment: Still the generated log file is empty. I can only see logs on console. In the above configuration 'xxx' is the root package. My project structure is as follows-
<project-name> -- src - -main -- java -- <package1> -- <package 2> -- <package 3>

I am substituting <package1> in place of 'xxx' in log4j2.properties file. Is that correct? or Do I need to put in something else.

Comment: @KetanDeopujari if you will substitute `package1`, then it will only print logging of `package1 classes`. Root package name could be the initial common part of all packages. Suppose your package name is `com.xxx` and `com.yyy` so `com` can be considered as Root package name and if you will write `com`, then it will print logs of classes in `com` package and its sub packages.